# Taxonomy term limit | how to bypass

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

Migrating to Drupal 8 - I find a new restriction - in Views filter - Taxonomy term field cannot be more than 128 characters.....

In Drupal 7 I never had seen such a restriction, or it was more longer.... I could easily put some 15 Taxonomy Terms, without a problem....

Now - I can not put in Views filter 15 Terms....

not in row, due to 128 character limit, and not in several separate filters - I get Null outcome, if I try to add several Taxonomy fields one by one with additional terms....

How to add 15 terms in Views filter now, in Drupal 8?!

Comment: I think it is obvious and clearly written - in D8 -> Views -> filter Taxonomy Terms (by depth) - there is a new 128 character limit, and I am not able to add enough Taxonomy terms...